# HeaderParseError in django email form

Tags: python, django, forms

When testing my email app, I get the following error:

HeaderParseError at /contact/
Expected 'atom' or 'quoted-string' but found '@'

I've been able to track the error down to the multiple variables containing just a '@', including 'recipients', but am having a hard time finding a fix.  I suspect it comes from the sanitized data, but even using just the POST object returned the same error.  Thanks in advance!  Here's the code:

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        recipient_list = list(str('xxxxx@gmail.com'))
        # recipient_list.append(from_email)

        ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation '''
        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        data = {
            'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
        result = r.json()
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

        email = EmailMessage(subject, message, str(from_email), recipient_list)
        email.send()
        if result['success']:
            messages.success(request, 'New comment added with success!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact')
    else:
        data = form.cleaned_data
        form = ContactForm(data, initial=data)
        messages.error(request, 'Please correct the errors on the form below.')

else:

    form = ContactForm()
return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line in your code:

```
recipient_list = list(str('xxxxx@gmail.com'))
```

If you run that in your console, you will get the following output:

```
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', '@', 'g', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'l', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm']
```

Which is not a list of valid email addresses! You need to do this instead:

```
recipient_list = ['xxxxx@gmail.com']
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  It's obvious now, but i was scratching my head for a couple of hours.